# Pandas swap substrings in column names

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I try to swap substrings in the column names of a DataFrame

| K_1[0,0] | K_1[0,1] | K_1[1,20] |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 34 | 77 |
| 99 | 42 | 23 |

where the result should look like this

| K_1[0,0] | K_1[1,0] | K_1[20,1] |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 34 | 77 |
| 99 | 42 | 23 |

So inside the parenthesis, the values before and after the comma should simply be interchanged.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DataFrame.rename` with a callable that employs a regular expression.

```
import re
df = df.rename(lambda c: re.sub('(.*)(\d+),(\d+)(.*)', r'\1\3,\2\4', c), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['K_1[0,0]','K_1[0,1]','K_1[1,20]'])

df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(r'^(.*)(\d+),(\d+)(.*)$', r'\1\3,\2\4')
print (df)      
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [K_1[0,0], K_1[1,0], K_1[20,1]]
Index: []
```